# Show that if $x_{0}=1$ and $x_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{x_n}$ then $|\varphi-x_n|\leq \frac{1}{\varphi^{n+1}}$ and $x_n\rightarrow \varphi$

Tags: induction, golden-ratio

I have tried out induction, there are some Formulars of phi that I have understood. For example $\varphi=1+\varphi^{-1}$ and $\varphi^2-\varphi=1$.

This is my attempt so far. I want to Show the inequality because then $x_n\rightarrow\varphi$ directly follows:

Inductionbase:

$\varphi-1=\varphi^{-1}$

The inductionbase is proved. Now the inductionstep:

$\varphi^{-(n+1)}=\varphi^{-1}\varphi^{-n}\overset{\text{IH}}{\geq}\varphi^{-1}|\varphi-x_{n-1}|$

What can I do now? I am stuck

Comment: Hope [this link](http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/number-theory/approximation-by-rationals/approximation-by-rationals.html) will help. Note that, the continued fraction of the Golden ratio $\phi=[1;1,1,1,\cdots ]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=0$, the inequality is obviously true. To make the induction work, suppose that 
$$
|\varphi-x_k|\leq \varphi^{-(k+1)}\Leftrightarrow \varphi-\varphi^{-(k+1)} \leq x_k \leq \varphi+\varphi^{-(k+1)}.
$$
We then have 
$$
|\varphi-x_{k+1}|=|\varphi-1-x_{k}^{-1}|=|\varphi^{-1}-x_{k}^{-1}|.
$$
Here things starts to get tricky because the thing inside abosolute value can be either positive or negative. When it is positive,
$$
|\varphi^{-1}-x_{k}^{-1}|=\varphi^{-1}-x_{k}^{-1}\leq \varphi^{-1}-\frac{1}{\varphi+\varphi^{-(k+1)}}=\varphi^{-1}-\varphi^{-1}\frac{1}{1+\varphi^{-(k+2)}}\\
=\varphi^{-1}(1-(1+\varphi^{-(k+2)})^{-1})=\varphi^{-1}(1-1+\varphi^{-(k+2)}-\varphi^{-2(k+2)}+\ldots)\leq \varphi^{-1}\varphi^{-(k+2)} \leq\varphi^{-(k+2)}.
$$

Therefore the inequality is also true for $n=k+1$.